# Sequence partially-applied Monadic Actions

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I'm aware this is probably obvious, but my hoogle-fu is failing me here. I have a list of actions of type:

```
import Data.Vector.Mutable (STVector)
[STVector s a -> ST s ()]
```

That is, a set of actions that take a starting MVector and mutate it in some way

I also have a starting vector

```
import Data.Vector         (Vector, thaw, freeze)
v :: Vector a
```

After thawing `v`, how do I sequence these actions into a final result?

```
doIt :: forall s. Vector a -> [STVector s a -> ST s ()] -> Vector a
doIt v ops = runST $ do
  v' <- thaw v
  -- do all the things to v'
  unfreeze v'
```

---

If context helps, I'm attempting Advent of Code's day 16 puzzle (part 2), so `ops` is a long list of mutations that I actually need to run through literally a billion times. I expected to be able to use `replicateM_` to do this, but can't see how to provide a starting value. I similarly thought `foldM_` would work, but I can't seem to get it to typecheck. Perhaps I'm doing something fundamentally wrong? I can't say I understand the ST monad backwards and forwards yet.

Comment: One problem is that type for `doIt` can't work. Try `Vector a -> (forall s. [STVector s a -> ST s ()]) -> Vector a` instead.

Comment: `traverse ($ v') ops`; which doesn't typecheck with your type signature, but does with @Carl 's.

Comment: @user2407038 Well, you want `traverse_` instead, given the constraints mentioned in the problem.But yeah, that should do.

Comment: @Carl Want to make that an answer?

Comment: @Davislor I suppose I had nothing else to do while my bus was stuck in traffic anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation you're looking for is `traverse_`. It visits each value in a data structure, applies a function with a monadic return type, and sequences their effects together while discarding their results. The "discarding their results" part is important. It means that the return type of `traverse_` in this case will be `ST s ()` instead of `ST s [()]`. The difference there is significant. It means that the operation won't build up a giant list of `()` values to eventually throw away.

The function you want to pass to `traverse_` is the one that means "apply a function to `v'`". That could be written as `\f -> f v'`, but there's a shorter version that's idiomatic and uses the `$` operator. Note that you can rewrite the lambda above as `\f -> f $ v'`, which can be rewritten as the section `($ v')`.

So you have `traverse_ ($ v') ops`, which is the correct operation, but it still won't type check. That's because of the type of `runST`, which requires that the type `s` in `ST s` be polymorphic. With your type signature as written, `s` is chosen by the caller of `doIt`. To make this work, you need to enable the RankNTypes extension by making sure `{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}` is at the top of the file, and then change the type to `Vector a -> (forall s. [STVector s a -> ST s ()]) -> Vector a`.  This narrowing of the scope of the `s` type variable requires that `s` be polymorphic in the value passed to `doIt`. With that restriction in place, `runST` will type check successfully with the operation above.

For more information on why `runST` has such a funny type, see [Lazy Functional State Threads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/1994/06/lazy-functional-state-threads.pdf), the paper which introduced the ST type and showed how it can be used to constrain mutability inside an externally-pure interface.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up! The link to the paper is especially helpful, even if I feel unqualified to read much of it past the abstract

Comment: @AdamSmith I felt the same way the first time I saw the paper. It's worth a read anyway. SPJ writes very clearly, even if you don't follow the math. And if you stick with Haskell, it will eventually click. It doesn't need to make perfect sense now.